# Info about "Wisdom is One" by Benjamin Williams Huntsman?

Tags: identification-request, textual-history

Ran across a title.  Out of curiosity, tried trolling the internet for more info.  No joy.  Does anyone know anything about a book titled "Wisdom is One" by Benjamin Williams Huntsman printed/copyrighted Jan 1, 2000?

Comment: Welcome to the site! The question is very short, so I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for here? You already have the title and author, unlike in most [tag:story-identification] questions. Do you need more publication info, or are you looking for where to buy the book, or do you want a plot summary, or what?

Comment: Shouldn't that be _"tried **s**trolling the internet for more info"_?

Comment: @Jenayah [see 4th meaning here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/troll)

Comment: @Rand TIL, though this meaning has one sad homonym

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the book was originally published in **1947**. Here are a few editions that I found:

- *Wisdom is one : being a collection of quotations from the sayings and writings of some of the masters and their followers, collated to show the fundamental identity of all veritable teachings* / compiled by B.W. Huntsman. This is the [edition from 2000 in the Library of Congres](https://lccn.loc.gov/99073734), but the note in the catalogue entry says, "Originally published: London : A. Dakers, **1947**."
- A [reprint by Watkins (London), **1953**](https://www.worldcat.org/title/wisdom-is-one-being-a-collection-of-quotations-from-the-sayings-and-writings-of-the-masters-and-their-followers-compiled-by-bw-huntsman-1st-ed-reprinted/oclc/561079518&referer=brief_results) listed in WorldCat.
- A [reprint by Stuart & Watkins, **1969**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0722400411), currently on Amazon.com. (This is presumably the same publisher as the previous one, possibly after a merger with another publisher.)
- A [reprint by C.E. Tuttle (Rutland, Vermont), **1985**](https://www.worldcat.org/title/wisdom-is-one-being-a-collection-of-quotations-from-sayings-and-writings-of-some-of-the-masters-and-their-followers-collated-to-show-the-fundamental-identity-of-all-vertitable-teachings/oclc/946484039&referer=brief_results) listed in WorldCat.
- A [reprint by Aeon (Mamaroneck, New York), **2000**](https://www.worldcat.org/title/wisdom-is-one-being-a-collection-of-quotations-from-the-sayings-and-writings-of-some-of-the-masters-and-their-followers-collated-to-show-the-fundamental-identity-of-all-veritable-teachings/oclc/56527908&referer=brief_results) listed in WorldCat.

Comment: Quick!  Tried LOC site but evidently need to work it more   Got TMI  & didn't wade through it all.  Excellent info.  Thnx.